# how to upload csv file in sqlite database django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I'm trying to upload csv through django but it's not working..

Code

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts  import render_to_response
from forms import UploadForm
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/url/')
    else:
        form = UploadForm()
    return render_to_response('upload.html', {'form': form})
```

**Url.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', create),
    #url(r'^articles/create/$', create, name='done'),
    url(r'^articles/create/$', 'article.views.create'),
)
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from time import time

def get_upload_file_name(instance, filename):
    return "uploaded_files/%s_%s" % (str(time()).replace('.','_'), filename)

class Article(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name)
```

**Forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from models import Article

class UploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
```

html file

> {% csrf_token %}
>       {{form.as_p}}

Comment: Are you sure the post form is valid?

Answer (score 0):

Your template needs to be:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{ form.as_p }}
   <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

See the [binding uploaded files to a form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files-to-a-form) section in the documentation.